# How to distinguish between syntax error and no rows found in Teradata

Tags: python, teradata

I am using Python 2.7 to have Teradata DB interaction. I am executing a TD  SQL query using Python and the results are being stored in .txt file. Everything is fine, but when there is a syntax error in the sql query or the query returns no rows, in these two cases I am getting an empty .txt file, so in case of getting an empty file I can not decide that whether there is a syntax error or there are no rows return by the query.
Is there any way in TD I can do that if there is no rows then it will only return the column headers in the txt file.(like mysql or Hana)

Thanks

Comment: There's a huge difference between *synax error* and *no rows returned*, but it's your Python code which has to deal with it, Teradata is not creating this file..

Comment: Yes I agree, but what I am doing is that I am setting a TD parameter _.export report file=results.txt_ which will store the result returned by the query. In both the cases _NO ROWS_ and _SYNTAX ERROR_ the file is empty.

Comment: Ok, you're running a BTEQ-Export, afaik there's no way to force column headers. How about deleting the file when there's an errror? Add a `.if errorcode <> 0 then .os del results.txt;` after the select.

Comment: That's correct. But I am running multiple queries at a time,out of which some are returning rows some are not & some are having syntax error, and trying to store all the results in a single file(results.txt). After that I have to identify the queries. This is the kind of requirement.

Comment: Would be much better if you tell that from the begining. Why do you store everything in a single file? You might add a `Select 'query failed'`  instead of `.os del` or try `ECHOREQ ERRORONLY` to get the failing query.